# X509 Certificate Modifying Distinguished Name Field

Tags: openssl, config, field, x509, distinguishedname

Due to size limitation, I would like to alter OpenSSL configuration file so then I would be able to generate smaller x509 certificates. Is it possible? If so, I would like to have a Pseudo ID instead of all distinguished name fields. When I want to generate a self-signed certificate using the new modified config file, it gives me an error:

error, no objects specified in config file
problems making Certificate Request
29749:error:0D06407A:asn1 encoding routines:a2d_ASN1_OBJECT:first num too large:a_object.c:109:

Any tip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this specifically answers your question regarding "generating smaller x509 certificates and whether it is possible"... However, I was getting the same error as you are getting about "first num too large".  Immediately afterward, I would have a subsequent error regarding "invalid field name ... countryName_default".  What I did was find "countryName_default" and comment it out.  Then I would get a new error regarding "invalid field name ... countryName_min"  So I commented that out.  In total, I commented out the following items (below), and then I stopped getting all errors including the error that you described.  It seemed to work after that.  Here are the items I commented out:

- countryName_default

  countryName_min

  countryName_max

  stateOrProvinceName_default

  0.organizationName_default

  organizationalUnitName

  organizationalUnitName_default

  commonName_max

  emailAddress_max

  challengePassword_min

  challengePassword_max

Comment: It looks good. The point is, X509 is standardized and if you change the fields it would be out of standard. What I did was to define my own certificate format and started to put the needed data into that from scratch.

Comment: CPPChase - Everyone else does it. They call them PKI profiles ;)

Comment: This also worked for me. Thank you! All the "_blah" values had to be commented out.